# Raspberry Pi Zero W - Docker

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, docker

I'm trying to start `resin/rpi-raspbian` image on a Raspberry Pi zero w and executing the command `/bin/bash`:

```
docker run -it resin/rpi-raspbian /bin/bash
```

But I didn't get the container console with that.

Although, on a Raspberry Pi 3 it works!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they had limited support for ARMv6 at one point and were planning to drop it entirely. Fortunately it would appear that proposal was reconsidered. Source: [link](https://github.com/alexellis/docker-arm/issues/17)

This is working for me on version 17.10.0-ce. If necessary make sure to update via

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```